# C# Process DataReceivedEventHandler works only once

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-game-engine, process

I have a Unity application that creates a process that tries to send commands to an Android device over adb shell. I am able to send commands over the course of the application. But I only receive output from the Android device the first time. I don't know if its a buffer issue with the OutputDataReceived. The inputs go through but I don't receive any logs on my Unity editor. If I turn Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow to true, I can see all the output in the adb shell that spawns outside Unity. The output is not getting redirected from that console to Unity after the first execution.

```
    public void StartShellProcessAsync ()
    {
        ShellThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            ShellProcess = new Process();
            ShellProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
            ShellProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell";

            ShellProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            ShellProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            ShellProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            ShellProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnOutputDataReceived);
            ShellProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnErrorDataReceived);

            ShellProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(OnProcessExited);

            ShellProcess.Start();
            ShellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            ShellProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
            ShellProcess.WaitForExit();
        });
        ShellThread.Start();
    }
```

I have buttons in Unity that sends commands like below:

```
am start -m <application activity>
am stack list
```

I am trying to read the output from `am stack list` It works if its the first command I send out. But if I run it after `am start -m <application activity>`, the output does not come through to Unity.

The reason why I'm running ShellProcess inside a thread is to have the process remain open throughout the application's execution. I don't want to spawn a new process for each command I send out to Android as its time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Try locking your thread. This ensures that only one process is active at a time.

There will be some conflict if a new thread is called while the other thread is busy doing the same process.

```
private readonly object balanceLock = new object();

//Place this code elsewhere
private void Instantiate_Shell_Once()
{

        ShellProcess = new Process();
        ShellProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
        ShellProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "shell";

        ShellProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        ShellProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ShellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        ShellProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        ShellProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnOutputDataReceived);
        ShellProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnErrorDataReceived);

        ShellProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(OnProcessExited);

}

public void StartShellProcessAsync ()
{
    ShellThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock(balanceLock)
        {

        ShellProcess.Start();
        ShellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        ShellProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        ShellProcess.WaitForExit();

       }
   });
   ShellThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be helping. Can't see any errors being thrown while doing that either.

Comment: @Anril I think you need remove some codes inside thread except `

`ShellProcess.Start();
        ShellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        ShellProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        ShellProcess.WaitForExit();`

Maybe the shell is created multiple times. Just execute those codes once.

Comment: I wasn't able to test thing again. I'll let you know when I do.